# Let $f:\mathbb R→ \mathbb R$ be given by $f(x)=⌊x^{3}⌋$

Tags: real-analysis

To explain *why* the function $f$ is integrable over any closed interval [a, b].

My answer currently would be: Given the function $f$ effectively maps to a series of integers in a discrete manner (and $f$ is bounded over closed interval), the graph can be partitioned into a series of constant functions. Given that in general we know that the set of upper Darboux sums and the set of lower Darboux sums are equivalent on constant functions, it is obvious that this function lies in the set of Riemann integrable functions over the interval $[a,b]$.

Am I missing anything? *comments say I should be more precise*

**Attempt 2**

Let us begin by describing our partition given the interval $[a,b]$.

Let |{$z \in \mathbb Z :z \in  [⌊a^3⌋,⌊b^3⌋]$}| $= n\lt\infty$. Consider the evenly distribution partition of $[a,b]$ defined as $P=${$x_i$ : $x_i = \frac{b-a}{k}$ where $k\le n$}.

But this would be wrong I realised as I can immediately think of something that won't work.

(I'll continue working on this)

Comment: Your argument isn't really precise enough. Is it so obvious that, say, $\lfloor x^{-3} \rfloor$ is integrable (given that the argument could be copy-pasted for that)?

Comment: I suppose, I had a suspicion, but how should I rewrite, define an actual partition over $[a,b]$ and show the supremum and infimum of each discrete section are equal?

Comment: It honestly depends on what tools you have available. It's important that your function only has finitely many (jump) discontinuities on any closed interval $[a, b]$; something like $\lfloor x^{-3} \rfloor$ doesn't.

Comment: I see. I'll edit my question with a more precise attempt, thank you @T.Bongers.

Comment: OH. I understand what you mean @T.Bongers, if a function has only a finite number of discontinuities, it's integrable. Thanks so much!

Comment: Answering the problem could depend on your definition of an *integrable* function.  For example, using Tom Apostol's (volume 1, 2nd edition) definition, all step functions are integrable.  Since your function is a step function, it is integrable.

Comment: A problem in Attempt 2: you can assume an evenly distributed partition. What you can use is a partition with maximum partition size less than $\delta$. Here, $\delta$ can be $\varepsilon/(|⌊b3⌋-⌊a3⌋|+1)$, so that the $U-L<\varepsilon$.

Comment: The simplest criteria here is that the given function is monotone. Any monotone function is Riemann integrable on any closed interval (proof is far simpler and you should try to prove this general result).

Answer (score 1):

I would try something along the lines:

$f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$ if it's bounded in $[a, b]$ and $\exists L\in\mathbb{R}$ if $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta_f(\epsilon)$ such that

given a partiton $\mathbf{P}$ of [a, b], if $\lVert P \rVert<\delta_f(\epsilon) \Rightarrow |S(f,\mathbf{P})-L|<\epsilon$

It's easy to see $f$ is bounded in any interval $[a, b]$, because $f$ is monotonic.

$f$ is discontinuous for $x\in \lbrace x:x=\lfloor x^3 \rfloor \rbrace $. Then f can be written as the sum of several functions:

Let $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Let $f_k = \begin{cases}
k &k=\lfloor x^3 \rfloor\\
0 &otherwise
\end{cases}$

in particular $f_k\neq 0$ only in $[\sqrt[3]{k}, \sqrt[3]{k}+1)$

$f=\underset{k\in \mathbb{Z}}{\sum}f_k$

$f \cap[a,b] = [a, b]\cap \underset{k\in \mathbb{Z}}{\sum}f_k = [a, b]\cap\underset{k\in \mathbb{Z}\cap [f(a), f(b)]}{\sum}f_k$

Now it's obvious that your function is Riemann integrable using the partition

$\mathbf{P_0}=\lbrace a < \lfloor a^3 + 1\rfloor^{1/3} < \lfloor a^3 + 2\rfloor^{1/3} < \dots < b \rbrace$

Then calculate S for that partition, taking into account that in each interval corresponding to a k, $f$ would be $f_k$ and that's constant

Then to make $\lVert P \rVert$ as small as you want adding more points, it won't change the fact that the sum would reduce to a constant function $f_k$ between the points of $\mathbf{P_0}$ and those are included in any other $\mathbf{P}$